# Concatenating 2 inputted lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, concatenation

I'm trying to combine 2 lists from input but I am getting an error every time.
Here is my code:

```
myAppend :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
myAppend a b = zipWith (+) a b
```

Getting this error:
"No instance for (Num a) arising from a use of ‘+’"

I was given this solution but it doesn't really make sense to me

```
myAppend :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
myAppend [] xs = xs
myAppend (y:ys) xs = y:(myAppend ys xs)
```

I don't really understand the second and third line.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "combine". Your function adds the lists elements pairwise, the other one concatenates the lists.

Comment: my bad I meant to concatenate them

Comment: You claim (in your type signature) that `myAppend` will work with lists of *any* type, whether that type supports `+` or not. But then you try to use `+` anyway. The correct type for `myAppend` would be `Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myAppend` does not concatenate two lists, it aims to sum elementwise the two lists, so `myAppend [1,4,2,5] [1,3,0,2]` will produce `[2,7,2,7]`. It will require a `Num a` constraint, since it can only work if the elements of the lists are `Num`bers:

```
myAppend :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
myAppend a b = zipWith (+) a b
```

As for the solution here it uses recursion. Lists in Haskell are like linked lists: you have a an empty list ("*nil*") which is represented by the `[]` data constructor, and a node ("*cons*") which is represented with `(x:xs)` where `x` points to the first item, and `xs` points to the list of remaining elements. So `[1,4,2,5]` is short for `(1:(4:(2:(5:[]))))`.

If we want to append `[1,4]` and `[2,5]` we thus want to produce a list `(1:(4:(2:(5:[]))))` out of `(1:(4:[]))` and `(2:(5:[]))`. This means we create a linked list with all the elements of the first list, but instead of pointing to the empty list `[]`, we let it point to the second list for the remaining elements. We do this through recursion:

```
myAppend (y:ys) xs = y : myAppend ys xs
```

will match if the first list unifies with the `(y:ys)` pattern. In that case we thus produce a list with `y` as first element, and the result of `myAppend ys xs` as as list of remaining elements ("tail"). Eventually we will thus call `myAppend ys xs` with the empty list `[]` as first item. In that case, we thus return the second list instead of the empty list, to append the second list to it.

We thus make calls that look like:

```
   myAppend [1, 4]     [2, 5]
=  myAppend (1:(4:[])) (2:(5:[]))
-> 1 : (myAppend (4:[]) (2:(5:[])))
-> 1 : (4 : (myAppend [] (2:(5:[]))))
-> 1 : (4 : (2:(5:[]))
=  [1, 4, 2, 5]
```

Comment: Where you wrote "(1:(4:[])) and (2:5:[])" is that correct or should it be (1:(4:[])) and (2:(5:[]))? Thanks

Comment: @user20338595 `:` associatse to the right, so `foo:bar:baz` and `foo:(bar:baz)` are the same thing.